# file_get_contents($remote_url) not working

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am working on a project where I need to fetch a .htm file from another server.
But `file_get_contents()` doesn't seem to work as it always returns this:

> file_get_contents(https://hvgg.de/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

This is my code

```
$url = "https://hvgg.de/vplan/f" . $day . "/subst_001.htm";

$opts = array("http" =>
    array("header" => "Connection: close")
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$f = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

If I run the very same code but on my localhost, everything works perfectly well and is quick.

This is an extract of my `php.ini`:

```
allow_url_fopen                 On
allow_url_include               Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off
```

**Note:** The server that I am trying to access uses ssl and a ssl certificate which is (as far as I know) not authorised by an authority.
I also tried cURL which didn't really work either, this is the output that `curl_getinfo()` returned:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://hvgg.de/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 63.11468
    [namelookup_time] => 0.005179
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 89.19.241.160
    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Any idea on what I could do?
I also read that maybe this is an error due to IPv6 or my `/etc/resolv.conf`. Could that be the case?

Comment: using localhost??? or live server?

Comment: this is all on my live server, but if I run the same script on my localhost, it works fine

Comment: did you tried with `$url = "http://hvgg.de/vplan/f" . $day . "/subst_001.htm";` with `http`

Comment: ?? Where is `$day` defined and loaded with something

Comment: Do you have the `open_ssl` extension activated?

Comment: @devpro the hvgg.de server automatically redirects me to https

Comment: @RiggsFolly where am I suppossed to activate it?

Comment: ok, what is the value of `$day` ??

Comment: @devpro either 1 or 2, it's a simple `$_GET`-variable

Comment: check your configuration as @RiggsFolly mentioned, its working fine on my side...

Comment: @devpro where can I check it?

Comment: in your `php.ini`

Comment: Here you can find the image of the part in question: [imgbox.com](http://imgbox.com/3t7cl8pl)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here you can find the image of the part in question: [imgbox.com](http://imgbox.com/3t7cl8pl)